# Small branches in modern CPUs

Tags: performance, x86-64, cpu-architecture, avx, branch-prediction

How do modern CPUs like Kaby Lake handle small branches? (in code below it is the jump to label LBB1_67). From what I know the branch will not be harmful because the jump is inferior to the 16-bytes block size which is the size of the decoding window.

Or is it possible that due to some macro op fusion the branch will be completely elided?

```
        sbb     rdx, qword ptr [rbx - 8]
        setb    r8b
        setl    r9b
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbx + 8]
        vmovdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbx + 16]
        cmp     cl, 18
        je      .LBB1_67
        mov     r9d, r8d
.LBB1_67:                               #   in Loop: Header=BB1_63 Depth=1
        vpcmpeqb        xmm0, xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbx - 16]
        vpmovmskb       ecx, xmm0
        cmp     ecx, 65535
        sete    cl
        cmp     rdi, qword ptr [rbx - 32]
        sbb     rsi, qword ptr [rbx - 24]
        setb    dl
        and     dl, cl
        or      dl, r9b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no special cases for short branch distances in any x86 CPUs.  Even unconditional `jmp` to the next instruction (architecturally a nop) needs correct branch prediction to be handled efficiently; if you put enough of those in a row you run out of BTB entries and performance falls off a cliff.  [Slow jmp-instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811901/slow-jmp-instruction)

**Fetch/decode is only a minor problem**; yes a very short branch within the same cache line will still hit in L1i and probably uop cache.  But it's unlikely that the decoders would special-case a predicted-taken forward jump and make use of pre-decode instruction-boundary finding from one block that included both the branch and the target.

When the instruction is being decoded to uops and fed into the front-end, register values aren't available; those are only available in the out-of-order execution back-end.

The major problem is that when the instructions after `.LBB1_67:` execute, the architectural state is different depending on whether the branch was taken or not. 
 And so is the micro-architectural state (RAT = Register Allocation Table).

Either:

- `r9` depends on the `sbb`/`setl` result (`mov r9d, r8d` didn't run)
- `r9` depends on the `sbb`/`setb` result (`mov r9d, r8d` did run)

Conditional branches are called "control dependencies" in computer-architecture terminology.  Branch-prediction + speculative execution avoids turning control dependencies into data dependencies.  If the `je` was predicted not taken, the `setl` result (the old value of `r9`) is overwritten by `mov` and is no longer available anywhere.

There's no way to recover from this after detecting a misprediction in the `je` (actually should have been taken), especially in the general case.  Current x86 CPUs don't try to look for the fall-through path rejoining the taken path or figuring out anything about what it does.

If `cl` wasn't ready for a long time, so a mispredict wasn't discovered for a long time, many instructions after the `or  dl, r9b` could have executed using the wrong inputs.  In the general case the only way to reliably + efficiently recover is to discard all work done on instructions from the "wrong" path.  Detecting that  `vpcmpeqb  xmm0, [rbx - 16]` for example still runs either way is hard, and not looked for.  (Modern Intel, since Sandybridge, has a Branch Order Buffer (BOB) that snapshots the RAT on branches, allowing efficient rollback to the branch miss as soon as execution detects it while still allowing out-of-order execution on *earlier* instructions to continue during the rollback.  Before that a branch miss had to roll back to the retirement state.)

---

Some CPUs for some non-x86 ISAs (e.g. PowerPC I think) have experimented with turning forward branches that skip exactly 1 instruction into predication (data dependency) instead of speculating past them.  e.g. [Dynamic Hammock Predication
for Non-predicated Instruction Set Architectures](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~taustin/papers/PACT98-dynpred.pdf) discusses this idea, and even deciding whether to predicate or not on a per-branch basis.  If your branch-prediction history says this branch predicts poorly, predicating it instead could be good.  (A Hammock branch is one that jumps forward over one or a couple instructions.  Detecting the exactly 1 instruction case is trivial on an ISA with fixed-width instruction words, like a RISC, but hard on x86.)

In this case, x86 has a `cmovcc` instruction, an ALU select operation that produces one of the two inputs depending on a flag condition.  **`cmove r9d, r8d` instead of `cmp`/`je` would make this immune to branch mispredictions, but at the cost of introducing a data dependency on `cl` and `r8d` for instructions that use `r9d`.  Intel CPU don't try to do this for you.**

(On Broadwell and later Intel, cmov is only 1 uop, down from 2.  cmp/jcc is 1 uop, and the `mov` itself is also 1 uop, so in the not-taken case `cmov` is also fewer uops for the front-end.  And in the taken case, a taken branch can introduce bubbles in the pipeline even if predicted correctly, depending on how high throughput the code is:  Whether queues between stages can absorb it.)

See [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2) for a case where CMOV is slower than a branch because introducing a data dependency is bad.

Comment: According to Henry's blog post on return address prediction (http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/), the BOB structure exists since SnB.

Comment: A quick test on Haswell shows that the impact of a conditional jump over a single instruction that is easily predictable on performance is less than 0.0001%.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I assume you'd find the same thing for an easily predictable branch with a much longer distance, though.

Comment: @HadiBrais - right, the impact of a branch can be easily be zero, but that's not a general statement: it can easily be more too, depending on the surrounding code. Taken branches are a known bottleneck for the front-end and it's easy to find examples where a taken branch slows down code by 100% or more versus the rearranged untaken version.

Comment: @PeterCordes: thanks for the tips! Didn't know about the Killer BOB. Are there rules of thumb to know when a branch doesn't need to be predicted (e.g. the register `rX` is ready `C` cycles before a cmp/je)?

Comment: @Stringer: Branches *always* need to be predicted before they're even decoded, let alone executed.  Fetch grabs machine code in 16-byte or 32-byte blocks, and it has to know which block to grab next after the current one to avoid front-end bubbles.  (Or similarly for the uop-cache).  But if your code isn't bottlenecked on front-end throughput, the miss penalty can be mostly hidden by OoO exec e.g. in a loop where the loop-exit mispredict can be "seen" well ahead of the main loop bottleneck.  [Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early](//stackoverflow.com/q/49932119)